# Jquery with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

JQuery is not detected in my app Django :

I have a html page links.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/mysheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

I have a html base  base.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   {% include "links.html" %}
</head>
<body>
{% load static %}
...
```

But when I want use js code in a page  X.html, it don't work :

X.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} <title> page X </title> {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <a href="#" id="linkID"> Blabla </a>
{% endblock %}
```

myscript.js

```
$("#linkID").click(function(){
    alert("ok it's good");
});
```

Nothing is display...
But when I use simple javascript (withoud jquery and ajax), it work !

In my settings.py, I have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS and I have this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying the static files in Django, we must be using a [`{% static %}` template command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) rather than specifying the path to the file.

The `link.html` can be modified as

```
{% load staticfiles %}
.....
.....

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/mysheet.css" %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/myscript.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: It don't work.. For css, my version it work. Now I have this error " Invalid block tag: 'static' "

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it works. But you forgot the quotes ^^ (src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}" )

Comment: @YassVegas Missed that :(. Thank you for pointing out. Corrected in the anwer.